# How to take a screenshot of a window and not the whole screen?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10-preview, microsoft-surface-pro-3

On a normal system, I'd go <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>PrtScr</kbd> for a screenshot of only the current frame. According to [the internet](https://pricklytech.wordpress.com/2014/08/06/surface-pro-3-quick-tip-no-printscreen-button-on-the-type-cover/), the correct procedure for Surface 3 is to go <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> but that only takes a snap of the whole desktop.

I've tried adding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to the combination but got nada. I have no idea what else to test.

How can I do that on my Surface 3?

Comment: I can't test this but: FN + Space = full screen and Alt + FN + Space = active window

Comment: @Rik The first combination doesn't work on my system. The second, neither. Did you forget to add *Win* key, there? If so, the first one would work but the second still fails to produce the needed behavior. More suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference in <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> on normal Windows. The first copies the complete screen to **the clipboard** the second also saves it to your **pictures-folder**. The second only works on [Windows 8](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12081.windows-8-capture-screenshots.aspx) and higher.

So:
<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> = Makes a screenshot and saves it to **your clipboard**
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> = Makes a screenshot of the **current Window** and saves it to **your clipboard**
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> = Makes a screenshot and saves it to **your pictures-folder**
(There is no equivalent function to save the **current window** to your **pictures**-folder.)

With the Surface Pro 3 these function are reached via:
<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> = Makes a screenshot and saves it to **your clipboard**
<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> = Makes a screenshot of the **current Window** and saves it to **your clipboard**
<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> = Makes a screenshot and saves it to **your pictures-folder**

(You can verify this by pasting in Word or Paint directly after using these functions.)

Edit *(a bit off-topic because it's not native Windows but you asked for alternatives)*:
You could, as an alternative, use [GreenShot](http://getgreenshot.org/). It has the ability to capture a window, a region and full screen with programmable function keys. It also has an editor and the ability to upload directly to imgur.com (which is really nice on sites like superuser.com).

Comment: Awesome, mate. There's only one thing missing in your reply - it's how to make a screenshot of the current window and save it to the pictures folder directly. But that's more of a MS blunder, so you're not to be blamed for that, hahaha. Very useful and comprehensive, +1.